# サイトに英語が残っている

Tags: バグ, 完了, 日本語, 英語, 投票

信用度が足りない状態で投票した時に出るメッセージが画像のように英語です。
[image]
画像の文章は、

> Thanks for the feedback! Once you eam total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score

です。

Comment: バグは再現できますか？確認宜しくお願いします。

Comment: @jmac もう直っているのですが、タグが不適切かなと思い編集しただけです。すみません。

Comment: 問題無いです！[status-completed]のタグをつけられるかどうかを確認したかっただけです！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

フィードバックというとサイトへの意見や感想のようだと思い、評価としてみました。

> 投稿を評価していただきありがとうございます！[信用度](/help/whats-reputation)が15点以上になれば、あなたも投票に参加することができます。

[Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/52633022?key=ea758c94063a449ed165c1d74afe20d9%7Cother)上で翻訳したので、近日中に反映されるかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございました。

Comment: 適用しましたので、次回のビルド（今日の昼ごろ？）にサイトへ反映します。