# 未翻訳：信用度が低いユーザーがプラス投票をした時のメッセージ

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

信用度が十分に稼げていないstack overflow新参者です。
他のユーザーの既存の回答にプラス投票をしたところ、青いボックスとともに下記のメッセージが現れました。

> Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

英語だな～と思いながら読んでいるうちに自動で消えてしまい、何度か連打して文をコピーしてようやく内容が読み取れました。
恐らくネイティブが読む速度を想定して自動で消しているのでしょうが、私のような非ネイティブにとっては時間内に読み切ることが困難なので、本件に限らず自動で消えるようなメッセージは優先的に翻訳していただけると嬉しいです。

なお、このメッセージについてはどうやら[一度は翻訳された](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2198/%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%81%AB%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%8C%E6%AE%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B)ようですが、原文を見てみると少し変化しているのでその変更の際に置き去りにされたようですね。

Comment: ありがとうございます！　ある条件下でしか出てこないような string はなかなか気づかれないので、このようなご指摘は非常に助かります。既に翻訳システム上で翻訳案が出たので、来週くらいには翻訳が反映されることになるのではないかと思います。暫くお待ちくださいませ。

Comment: そう言っていただけると報告したかいがあります。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

現状の翻訳システムの仕様では、日本語に翻訳済みでも原文(英語)が更新されると翻訳文もリセットされてしまうようです。該当箇所の翻訳については[新しい翻訳の提案](https://ja.traducir.win/string/4946)が既にされているので、反映までもうしばらく待ってみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。翻訳が活発そうで、ユーザーとしては喜ばしいです。

Comment: 翻訳が反映されたようです :)

Comment: 確認しました。ありがとうございました。